# Keyboard issue on multiple key presses

Tags: keyboard

I'm experience a strange issue with my keyboard in both Windows and Linux, so it's a keyboard issue.

When I need to have multiple keys pressed (like, press <kbd>X</kbd>, than <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> and finally <kbd>B</kbd>) the last letter didn't recognized and previous letter is repeated instead (so in text editor I have `xcvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv`). I have found multiple such combinations so far.

What is that? Is this some particular keyboard issue (I'm currently have wireless Genius SlimStar 8000ME, so, maybe this is a wireless issue?) or a general design flaw?

Comment: If you have a spare keyboard, check if this issue still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a high-end gaming keyboard that boasts of full [*n*-key rollover (NKRO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29). The specifications and manual don't seem to mention anything in this regard so I'm guessing n=3 for this keyboard.

Comment: Exactly, "cheep"keyboards usually have about a 3 key rollover, but some gaming keyboards have full key rollover I.E a corsair k70

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen by using several models of wireless keyboards is that they can't handle too many keys pressed down at the same time. It differs between the keyboards. For example, I have Microsoft Wireless keyboard and it can handle 3 keys at the same time while my other wireless keyboard from Deltaco only handles 2 keys.

So I would say that it isn't an particular keyboard issue, it is more a general issue with many wireless keyboards.